# How can I get the filename of a Word document from C#?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

I'm working on a MS Word AddIn (VSTO).
The idea is that I work on a Word document and I send it somewhere.

I have all the code I need except one thing: is there a way I can get the filename of the Word document I'm working on? (assuming that is already saved)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**this.FullName** property in the code-behind .cs file should give you the entire path of the current doc.

Here's the exact query in my QuickWatch window.

```
((Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document)(this)).FullName
```

Comment: I've done some time with VSTO... we need all the help we can. :)

Comment: The answer is correct but I saw a case where `Word 2010` opens a `.doc` file (compatibility mode) and, **sometimes**, for unknown reason (maybe permission thing) it replaces the name with a temporary generated name and the FullName property doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

the above did not work for me however this did

```
Document vstoDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(this.Application.ActiveDocument);
string name = vstoDocument.Name
MessageBox.Show(name);
```