# Word Add-in: How to get the filename of the Word document

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am creating an add-in in Word, and I want to get the file name that the add- in is working on. Can you advice me on how I can do that?

I have added the Microsoft 14.0 Object library but do not get the Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document reference as in this solution: [how can I get the filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792649/how-can-i-get-the-filename-of-a-word-document-from-c)

Comment: Hi Stuartd, I tried that particular solution but it doesnt work for me. I have installed Microsoft 14.0 object library but do not get Microsoft.Office.Tools reference.

Comment: OK reopening...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# : Word Add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715787/c-sharp-word-add-in)

Answer (score 0):

Word.ActiveDocument.FullName will give you the full path and file name

Word.ActiveDocument.Name will give you just the file name and extension

Word.ActiveDocument.Path will give you just the path to the active document

Comment: When you code this keep in mind ActiveDocument can be null (no active document) and all 3 of those properties can be null (FullName and Path will be if the document is new and not yet saved).

Comment: Thank You Rich and David, but the filename is null as mentioned. Is there a way that I can save the file with a new name? Also for some reason Word.ActiveDocument does not come up for me. Should I be adding a assembly reference?